# I'm using the Lateset version of Angluar and I get this error Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: angular, typescript, syntax-error

So when I used the $event with the onkeyup event and I want the value of the input filed to pass it to the filter Function it doesn't work

```
<div class="container mx-auto p-5">
  <div class="searchBar">
    <div class="field">
      <p class="control has-icons-left">
        <input #filterInput class="input" type="text" (keyup)="filterNotes($event.target.value)" placeholder="Filter">
        <span class="icon is-small is-left">
          <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the class componet :

```
filterNotes(query: string) {
    // some logic
}
```

Comment: There is no issue with this code, its working fine. Please check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mfwcx7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add to the

```
"angularCompilerOptions":{
    "strictDomEventtypes":false
}
```

in your tsconfig.json file

Answer (score 0):

In this context I think `$event.target` is not typed so typescript does not know what type of target it is, try the code below:

in the .html file pass only the event:

```html
...
<input (keyup)="filterNotes($event)">
...
```

in the .ts file modify your method to receive an event:

```
filterNotes(event: Event): string {
  const { value } = event.target as HTMLInputElement // forcing the type
  // the rest of yout logic goes here
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot it works for me :)

but I have another querstion (I watch this code from tutourial on youtube the code in the tutourial works fine but with me it doesn't work do you know why??!!)

Comment: Okay It seems the wrong in the ts.config file as the other answer .... but thank in advance :)